# R selecting duplicate rows

Tags: r, select, statistics, duplicates, dataframe

Okay, I'm fairly new to R and I've tried to search the documentation for what I need to do but here is the problem.

I have a data.frame called heeds.data in the following form (some columns omitted for simplicity)
eval.num, eval.count, ... fitness, fitness.mean, green.h.0, green.v.0, offset.0, green.h.1, green.v.1,...green.h.7, green.v.7, offset.7...

And I have selected a row meeting the following criteria:

```
best.fitness <- min(heeds.data$fitness.mean[heeds.data$eval.count >= 10])
best.row <- heeds.data[heeds.data$fitness.mean == best.fitness]
```

Now, what I want are all of the other rows with that have columns green.h.0 to offset.7 (a contiguous section of columns) equal to the best.row

I was thinking this might work

```
heeds.best <- heeds.data$fitness[
  heeds.data$green.h.0 == best.row$green.h.0 & ...
]
```

But with 24 columns it seems like a stupid method.  Looking for something a bit simpler with less manual typing.

Here is a short data sample to show what I want

```
eval.num, eval.count, fitness, fitness.mean, green.h.0, green.v.0, offset.0
1         1           1500     1500          100        120        40
2         2           1000     1250          100        120        40
3         3           1250     1250          100        120        40
4         4           1000     1187.5        100        120        40
5         1           2000     2000          200        100        40
6         1           3000     3000          150        90         10
7         1           2000     2000          90         90         100
8         2           1800     1900          90         90         100
```

Should select the "best" as row 4
Then I want to grab the results as follows

```
eval.num, eval.count, fitness, fitness.mean, green.h.0, green.v.0, offset.0
1         1           1500     1500          100        120        40
2         2           1000     1250          100        120        40
3         3           1250     1250          100        120        40
4         4           1000     1187.5        100        120        40
```

Data isn't actually sorted and there are many more columns but that is the concept

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is essentially *just* a complicated indexing question.  I have a solution here though there may be simpler ones.    I loaded your examples data into `DF`:

First, this gets us the best row index (easy using `which.min()`) :

```
R> bind <- which.min(DF[,"fitness.mean"])  # index of best row
```

Next, we `apply()` a row-wise comparison (over the subset of columns we care about, here index simply by position 5 to 7).

We use a comparison function `cmpfun` to compare the current row `r` to the best row (indexed by `bind`) and use `all()` to get rows where all elements correspond. [ We need `drop=FALSE` here to make it comparable on both sides, else `as.numeric()` helps. ]

```
R> cmpfun <- function(r) all(r == DF[bind,5:7,drop=FALSE])  # compare to row bind
```

This we simply `apply` this row-wise:

```
R> brows <- apply(DF[,5:7], 1, cmpfun)
```

And these are the rows we wanted:

```
R> DF[brows, ]
  eval.num eval.count fitness fitness.mean green.h.0 green.v.0 offset.0
1        1          1    1500         1500       100       120       40
2        2          2    1000         1250       100       120       40
3        3          3    1250         1250       100       120       40
4        4          4    1000         1188       100       120       40
R>
```

It did not matter that we use three columns for comparison -- all that mattered is that we had an indexing expression (here `5:7`) for the columns we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is an opportunity to show that `merge` is a powerful R function.

Using these data:

```
dat <- read.csv(textConnection('eval.num,eval.count,fitness,fitness.mean,green.h.0,green.v.0,offset.0
1,1,1500,1500,100,120,40,
2,2,1000,1250,100,120,40,
3,3,1250,1250,100,120,40,
4,4,1000,1187.5,100,120,40,
5,1,2000,2000,200,100,40,
6,1,3000,3000,150,90,10,
7,1,2000,2000,90,90,100,
8,2,1800,1900,90,90,100'))
```

We calculate the following:

```
  imin <- which.min(dat$fitness)                     ## identify min row
  dupcols <- c('green.h.0', 'green.v.0', 'offset.0') ## dup cols for checking
  merge(dat, dat[imin, dupcols], by=dupcols, all=F)
```

Gives

```
>   merge(dat, dat[imin, dupcols], by=dupcols, all=F)
  green.h.0 green.v.0 offset.0 eval.num eval.count fitness fitness.mean
1       120        40       NA        1       1500  1500.0          100
2       120        40       NA        2       1000  1250.0          100
3       120        40       NA        3       1250  1250.0          100
4       120        40       NA        4       1000  1187.5          100
```